# Is the definition of all non-standard bases dependent on the standard basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space over field $\mathbb{K}$ and let $\alpha$ be a vector in $V$. Let $B = \{b_1, ..., b_n\}$ be a basis of $V$. When we say $\alpha=(x_1, \ldots, x_n)_B$ we only mean $\alpha= x_1b_1 + \ldots + x_nb_n$. There is nothing else essential to the definition of the coordinates of a vector.

Now, regardles of the basis with respect to which we refer to a vector, such vector is assumed to be the same. Coordinates and basis are a matter of *notation*, and bear no effect on that which is being denoted.

Now, let us use $\mathbb{R}^2$ to exemplify my doubt. Let us define a non-standard basis for this space; for example, $B = \{(3, 2), (1, 9)\}$. Such definition already depends on the intelligibility of the expressions $(3, 2), (1, 9)$, which are assumed to be coordinates under the standard basis.

Of course one could make the matter uglier by letting $B = \{(x_1, x_2)_{B'}, (y_1, y_2)_{B'} \}$ where $B'$ is another basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$. But the point is the same: the definition of this basis also requires the use of another.

Hopefully my confusion is beginning to be apparent. Yes, formally speaking the definition of a basis is flawless, since it is defined in terms of vectors (not other bases). But when we are faced with actually defining particular bases, we always require another, which raises the question: where did the definition of that other come from?

To conclude, suppose we say $(x_1, x_2)_B = (y_1, y_2)_A$ for basis $A, B$. This can only mean $x_1\textbf{b}_1 + x_2\textbf{b}_2 = y_1\textbf{a}_1 + y_2\textbf{a}_2$. But to actually compute such operation we require $\textbf{b}_i, \textbf{a}_i$ to be defined in terms of some basis as well... Otherwise, how do we know what the scalar multiplications are? So once again, what should that basis be? It is generally assumed to be the standard basis. Which brings the question: is the definition of all non-standard bases dependent on the standard basis?

Comment: “Such definition already depends on the intelligibility of the expressions $(3,2),(1,9)$ which are assumed to be coordinates under the standard basis.” No, they are not the coordinates of anything. They are literally elements of the set in question. The set is $\Bbb{R}^2$, whose elements are by definition tuples (ordered pairs) of real numbers. That’s it. So, $(3,2)$ is literally an element of the set $\Bbb{R}^2$.

Comment: You raise a good question. Specifying vectors in $\Bbb R^n$ requires some sort of underlying coordinates, I agree. But what if my vector space is the set $P_2$ of all polynomials of degree $\le 3$? Then I can specify the polynomial $f(x) = 3x^2+5x-7$ without any reference to a basis for $P_2$. If my vector space is the set of all continuous functions on $[0,1]$ (with obvious addition and scalar multiplication), I certainly don't need a basis to specify the vectors $\sin x$ and $e^{5x}$.

Comment: P.S. Typo. Degree $\le 2$.

Comment: Thank you all for these comments, they were very clarifying.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just adding this answer to complement the other answers and comments already given:

I think part of the confusion here relates to two different interpretations of tuples. As an element of $\mathbb{R}^2$, the pair $(1,2)$ has first coordinate $1$ and second coordinate $2$ *by definition*. These coordinates *constitute* the pair and are *intrinsic* to it, and do not depend on any basis.

On the other hand, we can also use pairs in $\mathbb{R}^2$ to *represent* vectors in any $2$-dimensional real vector space $V$ relative to any chosen basis $B$. In this case the coordinates so obtained are not intrinsic to the vectors represented in $V$, because they depend upon the particular basis $B$.

It can get very confusing when we take $V=\mathbb{R}^2$ in the second case here and have multiple possible interpretations for pairs and coordinates within the same space, so it's important to distinguish these different meanings.

Comment: To give a *geometric* realization (in the cartesian plane) of an ordered pair, we need some coordinate system, and this corresponds to a basis.

Comment: @TedShifrin I prefer to just draw the numerals themselves in a random location in the plane. It's not at all useful but it *is* geometric, and doesn't require a basis. ;)

Comment: Your “random” locations of $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ give the basis. *Shrug*

Comment: @TedShifrin Often I randomly choose the same point for different pairs, so that might not be true. My geometry teachers were always frustrated with me.

Comment: That would be disruptive indeed. As a geometer, I reject you entirely!

Comment: Thank you for taking the time of answering this question. Your answer hits the nail in the head in what comes to what was confusing me!

Answer (score 4):

I think this is the crux of your problem:

> But when we are faced with actually defining particular bases, we
> always require another,

What you really need when faced with actually defining a particular basis is not another basis, it is *some way of actually describing the vectors in the space*.

If the space is given to you as $\mathbb{R}^2$ then you are told that each vector is a pair of numbers --- so, as you have observed, essentially its expression in terms of the standard basis.

But suppose the space is the space of all functions that solve the differential equation
$$
y'' + y = 0.
$$
That is a vector space, since the sum of any two solutions is again a solution, as is a scalar multiple of any solution.

There is no "standard basis" to begin with.
It turns out that space is two dimensional, and that
$$
( \sin x ,   \cos x)
$$
is a basis. That basis is in fact the one most commonly used for this space.

Answer (score 1):

Vector spaces pre-exist to their basis. E.g. given some set $X,$ the real vector space $\Bbb R^X$ of maps from $X$ to $\Bbb R$ needs no basis for the definition of its operations.

And $\Bbb R^n$ is the particular case $X=\{1,2,\dots,n\}.$

Another particular case, for which there is even no "standard basis", is $X=\Bbb N.$