# Is a choice of basis needed to express a vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ as a tuple?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Let $\mathbb{R}^3$ be equipped with the standard operations that make it a vector space. Then any element of $\mathbb{R}^3$ is called a vector. Every element $v \in \mathbb{R}^3$ can be expressed as a tuple $v=(x,y,z)$ with $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}$ by definition. Now, this has the property that if $e_1=(1,0,0),e_2=(0,1,0),e_3=(0,0,1)$ denotes the canonical basis vectors, we get that $v=x \cdot e_1+y \cdot e_2 + z \cdot e_3.$ When choosing a different basis, say $B=\{b_1,b_2,b_3\}$, there are (in general different) real numbers $a,b,c$ such that $v=a \cdot b_1+ b \cdot b_2 + c \cdot b_3$. The [concept of coordinate vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_vector) gives that $v$ can be written as $(x,y,z)$ with respect to the canonical basis and as $(a,b,c)$ with respect to $B$.

Questions: $(1)$ When noting that every vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ can be written as a tuple $(x,y,z)$, is this implicitly based on choosing a basis? That is, did we implicitly choose the standard basis here? To my mind this is not the case, because we don't even need to introduce the concept of a basis to note that by definition, any vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$, which is not more or less than an element of $\mathbb{R}^3$, can be written as such an object without mentioning any basis. However, when introducing the concept of a basis later, we see that the standard basis has the nice property that every vector $(x,y,z)$ can be written as $x \cdot e_1+y \cdot e_2+ z \cdot e_3$.

$(2)$ Why does it make sense that we interpret the same thing, namely an element of $\mathbb{R}^3$ differently depending on the situation? When we use the standard basis we interpret $(x,y,z)$ to be the arrow obtained by having as its coordinates $(x,y,z)$ whereas when using the basis $B$ we interpret $(x,y,z)$ to be the arrow that has as its coordinates $(x,y,z)$ w.r.t. $B$, which are totally different in general, despite them being the same thing mathematically, namely the same element of the set.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the definition of all non-standard bases dependent on the standard basis?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4623337/is-the-definition-of-all-non-standard-bases-dependent-on-the-standard-basis)

Answer (score 2):

Outside of being a vector space, $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a set formed from the Cartesian product of three copies of $\mathbb{R}$. In that sense, the element $(x, y, z)$ is simply the ordered triple with first element $x$ and so forth.

If we are treating $\mathbb{R}^3$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ with the normal element-wise operations, then we automatically get the standard basis for "free" - because of the way vector addition and scalar multiplication are defined, it is automatically true that $(x, y, z) = x(1, 0, 0) + y(0, 1, 0) + z(0, 0, 1) = x \mathbf{e}_1 + y \mathbf{e}_2 + z \mathbf{e}_3$ without needing to explicitly provide a particular basis.

We can then separately think about $\mathbb{R}^3$ as being a 3-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ without thinking directly about ordered triples, in which case we know that for *some* basis $B$ we can express an arbitrary vector as $\mathbf{v} = a_1 \mathbf{b}_1 + a_2 \mathbf{b}_2 + a_3 \mathbf{b}_3$.

Then because of how vector spaces work, for a lot of purposes it doesn't actually matter what our basis is because we can translate from one basis to another isomorphically, i.e. there is a bijection $\varphi: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ such that for bases $B$ and $B'$ we have $\varphi(\mathbf{b}_i) = \mathbf{b}'_i$ and all of the important vector space properties are preserved through this change of basis.

*Further*, we can find an isomorphism between the vector space $\mathbb{R}^3$ as expressed via ordered triples, and the vector space of "arrows in 3D Cartesian space", to the extent that we often don't even think about them as being different things.

Generally, if we say two mathematical objects are isomorphic, it means that within the structure of interest there's no functional difference between the two, because any operations we might apply to one object can be directly transformed into an equivalent operation in the other. However, if there is additional structure outside of that then it may not be preserved by the isomorphism - for example, $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the canonical basis and $\mathbb{R}^3$ with a different basis may be isomorphic as vector spaces, but the differences between them become apparent when we look at them as metric spaces, or algebras, or some other object. That's why it's important to note the context we're working in to know what assumptions are being made.